# How to fix javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException Invalid credentials

Tags: java

Though I have used correct credentials I am unable to read emails using java

I have tried pop3 AND IMAP. All are displaying invalid credentials for all the EmailId's tried

```
Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(new Properties( ));
Store store = session.getStore("imaps");
store.connect("imap.googlemail.com", 993, "example@gmail.com", password);
Folder inbox = store.getFolder( "INBOX" );
inbox.open( Folder.READ_ONLY );

// Fetch unseen messages from inbox folder
Message[] messages = inbox.search(
    new FlagTerm(new Flags(Flags.Flag.SEEN), false));

// Sort messages from recent to oldest
Arrays.sort( messages, ( m1, m2 ) -> {
  try {
    return m2.getSentDate().compareTo( m1.getSentDate() );
  } catch ( MessagingException e ) {
    throw new RuntimeException( e );
  }
} );

for ( Message message : messages ) {
  System.out.println( 
      "sendDate: " + message.getSentDate()
      + " subject:" + message.getSubject() );
}
```

I should be able to  read email

Comment: I disabled two way authentication also

Comment: There could be chances that Gmail account's third party access security check is disabled.

Comment: I have enabled  less secure app and now I got Username and password not accepted.

Comment: There are lots of solution for your error ... check this ..https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/unable-to-send-mail-through-smtp-gmail-com

Comment: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windowslive/forum/all/username-and-password-not-accepted-by-popgmailcom/c61c8736-e91c-4262-a004-96ae7c3639a0

Comment: for solve this problem you welcome read my answer here
https://stackoverflow.com/a/72592946/2347210

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The reason is that email box doesn't allow connections from less secure apps.
Your code is fine.

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: [AUTHENTICATIONFAILED] Invalid credentials (Failure)
    at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.protocolConnect(IMAPStore.java:474)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:275)
```

The above exception is thrown when less secure app access is tured OFF. Turn this ON to make the access available via program.

[image]

Comment: I have enabled less secure app and now I got Username and password not accepted.

Comment: Post the exception trace, as I tested your code and it worked fine for me

Comment: google no longer support this option.

Comment: no longer support this option here the updated answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/72592946/2347210

Answer (score 3):

Google no longer support 'Less Secure App Access'.
Instead you need to enable 2- step verification on your google account and generate an app password to use with your mail application.

Use full links:

1. [2- step verification](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185839)
2. [Create and use app password](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833)

[Gmail SMTP example](https://mkyong.com/java/javamail-api-sending-email-via-gmail-smtp-example/)

Comment: Thank you @Nandan for the update. This solution helps after google policy changes.